# How to compare image file name with string in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How do I compare image file name (which is set as my ImageView image resource) with a string?

I want to compare currently used image resource with defined string and if it matches then change it to a different image (by clicking a button).
I want to precisely define what image should be displayed next (depending on what button is clicked and which image is currently shown) and I want to do it many times (I know how to switch images with ImageSwitcher or how to change image with a button click, but it's not enough).

Edit:
So far I did something like this. I wanted to get current ImageView content description and then compare it. Bu of course it's not working because it describes the content of ImageView, not the Image itself. But it shows the idea what I want to do.

```
    val imageView = findViewById(R.id.display) as ImageView
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one)

    val imageName = imageView.getContentDescription()

    val buttonYes : Button = findViewById(R.id.yesButton)
    val buttonNo : Button = findViewById(R.id.noButton)


    when  {
        (imageName.equals(one))-> buttonYes.setOnClickListener { imageView.setImageResource(two) }
        (imageName.equals(one))-> buttonNo.setOnClickListener { imageView.setImageResource(three) }
        (imageName.equals(two))-> buttonYes.setOnClickListener { imageView.setImageResource(five) }
        }
```

Comment: ciao and welcome to StackOverflow! can you please post your attempts so far in order to be better helped to solve your question? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A way (or trick) to solve this is to store the name of the drawable in the imageview's tag:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one)
imageView.tag = "one"
```

and then compare the tag:

```
when (imageView.tag.toString()) {
    "one" -> buttonYes.setOnClickListener { imageView.setImageResource(two) }
    "two" -> buttonYes.setOnClickListener { imageView.setImageResource(five) }
}
```

if you don't want to hardcode the id then use this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one)
imageView.tag = resources.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.one)
```

Comment: thank you! that was very heplful! I used your idea and made some other changes to my code (like getting "setOnClickListner) before when) and it's working just like I wanted it to!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
 String1 = "nameOne"; 
 String2 = "nameTwo";
```

and by using `in` operator

```
String2 in String1
```

Or you can use

```
"nameOne".contains("nameTwo", ignoreCase = true)
```

Comment: Case usually matters when it comes to files though, so setting `ignoreCase` to true might not be the best idea